# I just bought a house and found this mold. What should I do about it?

Tags: kitchens, mold, kitchen-counters

I have found mold in the corner of the kitchen and it seems to have spread to the lower kitchen counter as well as the wall behind it. I can't see anything in the middle since there are some tiles.

[image]

[image]
Is it okay to stay in the house and would it be okay to store pots in the kitchen counter near the mold or should I cover it with something? If anyone knows, how would I go on about treating this?

Comment: Unless you bought the house "as is", you might be able to get the sellers to fix it.  Properly this time.  You need to have the mold tested to find out the type to see if it is just icky or the get out now type.  Mold likes moisture/dampest so there is or was a leak near there that you were not aware of.

Comment: Your "is it ok" questions are off topic here as highly subjective. If you want help _fixing_ the problem, please revise to ask just about that. See the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: the house doesn't have isolation on the outside, so i'm guessing that could be the source? sadly, the sellers no longer have any part in this

Comment: The sellers might not have a choice.  They are usually required to fix or tell of any safety/building problems to the buyers.

Comment: Did you get an inspection?

Comment: @crip659 I don't know what market you live in to think that a seller should fix it. But here in California where the market is hot, the best we were able to do was get a small credit to the repair.

Comment: @Shock does this space have high humidity? How is the ventilation in the space? you need to add more context.

Comment: I have contacted some businesses about an inspection, but there isn't many of them that do this sort of thing around here. I'll try to get someone more professional before spraying anything.

Comment: The space would have high humidity from the cooking I would guess. This corner is the outer corner and the ventilation is poor up there, so I think a combination of no isolation, poor ventilation and humidty from cooking would be the cause.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking the wrong question. "What should I do about it?" Contact a remediation service. Not only do you need to massively renovate this space, you need to identify the source.

I disagree that there's any value to testing mold. Certainly, people sell the services, and there are labs that can identify the species of molds. All molds are potentially dangerous. It depends on your own immunocompetence. Anything short of the most conservative option (i.e. stay out of the house until it's fully restored) is a gamble with your health.

Comment: Thank you, I have contacted some services, so I'm waiting for their response. The issue is that I have no where else to go since my current apartment is already sold

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know what type of mold is to have it tested. As far as treating it, get some 12% hydogen peroxide and a good spray bottle. Saturate the area and let it sit for 10 to 15 minutes. Then scrub and wipe down the area. Keep an eye on the area to make sure the mold doesn't reappear Don't use bleach, it's good for surface cleaning but is doesn't sink down into the spores.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I  feel this is dangerous advice. While the risk of black mold is probably overstated, I would not advise anyone to not test. Especially when it is such a large area and we cant tell if its dried or still living with spores.

Comment: @RohitGupta  With all due respect, Doesn't my first sentence lead the OP to have it tested?

Comment: This is terrible advice. Testing (in my experience) is hundreds to thousands of dollars. We paid over a $1,200 for our recent home. In this pic IT IS VERY CLEAR that they have mold. Why waste the money. Go straight into remediation. 

It is irresponsible to just spray and see what happens. For everyone in the household. 

If this is a rented property he could run into legal liability. I would recommend updating your answer or deleting as it is of no value.

Comment: @JGallardo  I beg to differ.  Yes, testing costs $$  but it's the only way to tell if it' the dangerous type to answer part of the OP's question.  I live in S Florida, mold capitol of the world , and hydrogen proxide is an excellent  course of action before ripping out your kitchen. I've used it hundreds of times and it stops the mold dead in it's tracks.  We can get mold tested here for a few 100 bucks.